# selenium with python Select item from dropdown which is in <li> bag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an element from the drop-down list. I notice that my elements to select are not in the option tag but in the li tag as shown in the following html example

```
<select name="_itil_assign[units_id]" id="dropdown__itil_assign_unit_id_857661577" data-select2-id="dropdown__itil_assign_unit_id_857661577" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="0" data-select2-id="42">-----</option></select>

....................

<span class="select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--open" style="position: absolute; top: 571px; left: 86px;">
<span class="select2-dropdown select2-dropdown--above" dir="ltr" style="width: 232px;">
<span class="select2-search select2-search--dropdown" style="display: inline;">
<span class="select2-results">
<ul id="select2-dropdown__itil_assign_units_id_857661577-results" class="select2-results__options" role="listbox"role="listbox" aria-hidden="false">
<li class="select2-results__options" role="option" aria-selected="true" data-select2-id="44">
<li class="select2-results__option" title="unit_1" role="option" aria-selected="false"></li>
<li class="select2-results__option" title="unit_2" role="option" aria-selected="false"></li>
<li class="select2-results__option" title="unit_3" role="option" aria-selected="false"></li>
.........
</ul></span></span></span>
```

I tried with the following code but it doesn't work

```
unit = Select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//select[@name='_itil_assign[unit_id]']"))
unit.select_by_value(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/span[2]/span/span[2]/ul/li[3]"))
```

try to select one option from dropdown menu